# Automotive: VCC and signal filters at each IC?

Tags: filter, signal-integrity

I'm designing an automotive product (sensors / LTE / GPS / etc). I've taken into account some primary 12V input filtering (TVS, reverse polarity, over-current). Everything works fine on our test motorcycle, but I'm afraid other bikes might be more noisy (especially if placed closer to the engine/alternator). Once the 12V goes into the buck and then linear regulator and is fed out to the PCB, it can pick up noise again(?). It's a 4 layer design with the 3.3V and GND as inner layers.
Is it necessary, like a 1st or 2nd order RC filter, at the VCC (3.3V) of every IC (in addition to the always needed 100nF decoupling capacitor)?
And how do I determine how the filter should be designed (R or C in series and parallel) and how to calculate values?

Comment: Define your ‘noise’. Both the buck and linear reg will significantly reject some forms of noise. What you describe as ‘input filtering’ is input protection. I see no filtering described.

Comment: Schematic diagrams help get good answers. You should post one.

Comment: @okwestern you can edit the question and there is a circuit tool button, please draw a schematic.

Comment: How would noise enter the system? 1. Are the majority of components shielded, or at least installed on a ground plane? (Of course GPS and LTE antennas need access.) 2. What other leads enter the case? You *might* need filtering at each lead... or not.